# Required message error on not required (nullable) field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I did some research about this problem, but NOTHING comes close to MY difficulty.

Here's my SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Departement] (
[IdDepartement] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Description]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
[IsActif]       BIT            NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdDepartement] ASC)
);
```

As you can see, IsActif IS null.

Here's part of my Departement.cs :

```
public Nullable<bool> IsActif { get; set; }
```

Once again, everything is normally nullable.

Here's part of my Metadata (for not loosing the annotations when the database is updated) :

```
[UIHint("YesNo")]
public Nullable<bool> IsActif { get; set; }
```

Still, a nullable force of the nature, **without** [Required]! (If someone wonders what is a UIHint: it is connected to a DisplayTemplate and it just presents nicely my bit value).

Just for the curious ones, because I feel my question will not be complete if I do not put everything in here. Here's my UiHint:

```
@model Nullable<bool>

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    if (Model.Value)
    { <text>Oui</text> }
    else
    { <text>Non</text> }
}
else
{ <text>Indéfini</text> }
```

It clearly states if Model Has Value   ON Nullable!!!

But this is what I get when a try to Create a new department:
[which means 'the field IsActif is required.'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANZAr.png)

Someone has an idea what is going on? All my other nullable booleans work perfectly. Is there's a place I forgot to look? What's the next step?
If someone have an idea, please let me know. I did pet my computer to make this work, but I am about to eat it now.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Mea Culpa: Oooooooooh, I so want to die. I just realised I was using a ViewModel and I should check there. And there it was, the culprit looking at me with a devilish snigger. I am sorry for this newbie mistake and for my punishment, I will close this question and mark it as answered and leave it here for everybody to laugh at me and just in case another newbie have the same problem. I still do not understand why my others nullable boolean worked, while they were in the same situation, though...

Comment: <input type="text" required>

Comment: Do you get that message after server-side validation? Or before you submit the data? Show us the form and controller action that uses `IsActif`.

Comment: @Woshooo ?!? I'm sorry, I do not understand what you mean. I don't want this field to be required.

Comment: @Jasen I get it just after I click on "Create".

Comment: If you haven't found the answer with other questions on SO you could post your solution here so it might help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go see my Edit. I am too shameful to repeat it here. Thanks anyway to those who took their time to add comments, specially Jasen.

In big:

EmployeViewModel **before**:

```
public bool IsActif { get; set; }
```

EmployeViewModel **after**:

```
public Nullable<bool> IsActif { get; set; }
```

Now I just have to hide myself under a carpet.